# C++TMP how to parse runtime array to variadic meta-template?

Tags: c++, arrays, parsing, c++11, template-meta-programming

i've made my variadic **meta template** work (take any number of int args)

```
cout << findBestSum<4,5,6,3,7,20,3,50,1,-1,5>::result << endl; //outputs 103 which is good
```

now i meet a problem of passing a runtime input to this template, for example the standard **argv** (after converting it to int of course), as it is a pointer, and **pointers don't exist in compile-time** calculations.

is there a way to extract / expand / parse the input array as separate arguments into the template?

*i could of course do something like*

```
 findBestSum<arr[0],arr[1],arr[2]>::result
```

*if i knew the number of arguments overhead, but i don't. the user can even input a million numbers.*

p.s. just reminding, **i can't** do it this way: `findBestSum<arr>::result` because it is a pointer!! no addresses are assigned at compile-time

Comment: _"now i meet a problem of passing a runtime input to this template"_ You cannot. Templates are evaluated at compile time, period.

Comment: There's a bit of confusion between compile-time and run-time constructs. I suggest clearing that out before attempting any further.

Comment: It's impossible. Rewrite it as a usual function. I wonder why you wrote a template for that.

Comment: expected something like this.
is it possible to precalculate the metatemplate for some range of integer inputs and then pull the one result matching the runtime request?

Comment: Write a program that precalculates the result for whatever inputs you need, and store it in a data file, in a format convenient for lookup. Or even generates a C++ source building a data structure, that you can compile together with your project. Templates are simply the wrong tool for this problem.

Comment: this was actually a useful answer. please repost it as answer and ill mark it a good one!
p.s. i need the runtime to be as fast as i can (very critical), so i've got to use this dark tactic

Answer (score 0):

Templates are the wrong tool for the job in this case since your sequence of numbers isn't known at compile-time.

If your `findBestSum` algorithm searches for the maximum subarray containing the maximum sum (i.e. [Maximum subarray problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) with Kadane's algorithm) and is O(N) **and** the array is only known at runtime, you have no choice but to go through all the elements of your array at runtime and execute the algorithm.

Depending on your user's input precalculating all the possible permutations of the input values according to their value range might be completely unfeasible or *kinda* make sense. This is beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: actually implemented it using both templates and constexpr in the end. works. fully metaprogrammed. http://prnt.sc/8x6tlo